# IOS/Objective-C: can't display core data information

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

My app follows the scheme web(json)->appDelegate (Core Data)->ViewController. So far I can see the locations I got from serialized json and all the other new ones I input for testing. But now I'm trying to display them in a tableview, and so far it's not working. The table remains empty, although I know the locations are in the Core Data: Here's the code:

```
#import "TableTableViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Spot.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"




@interface TableViewController ()

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *locations;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]){
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Spot"];
    self.locations = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return self.locations.count;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSManagedObject *ls = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ls valueForKey:@"name"]]];


    return cell;
}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
If I log the locations-> NSLog(@"%@ the locations are", _locations); I get a null result. This means that the fetched data isn't populating the array, therefore, the table stays empty, right? But why the array isn't being populated?

Comment: I need to check if my data base isn't empty? How can I do that?

Comment: For a sanity check, I'd put a break point in the numberOfRowsInSection method to make sure it's getting called and then, if it does get hit, print out the result of self.locations.count and make sure that isn't 0.  If that breakpoint trips and the count is greater than 0, then you have data.

Comment: Have you tried @conarch's suggestions?

Comment: How can I implement that suggestion? I'm kind of new at this; it's my first app...

Comment: Update: if I log the locations, like this 

[self.tableView reloadData];
     NSLog(@"%@ lisbon", _llocations);

I get a null result. This means that the array isn't receiving the fetched Data, right? But why?

Comment: is the managedObjectContext nil?

Comment: how are you saving the data? are you doing it in a background context?  are you merging the changes from the background context to the main thread context?

Comment: Thank you all for the attention, but the problem is solved; basically I had a method in a nsobject class, so all I did was: 
    
    _locations = [Spot allSpots];

Answer (score 0):

Check that your self.tableView.dataSource is not nil

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont get it

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;//add this